# BASH: File sorting according to file name

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk, sed

I need to sort 12000 files into 1000 groups, according to its name and create for each group a new folder containing files of this group. The name of each file is given in multi-column format (with _ separator), where the second column is varied from 1 to 12 (number of the part) and the last column ranged from 1 to 1000 (number of the system), indicating that initially 1000 different systems (last column) were split on 12 separate parts (second column).

Here is an example for a small subset based on 3 systems divided by 12 parts, totally 36 files.

```
7000_01_lig_cne_1.dlg
7000_02_lig_cne_1.dlg
7000_03_lig_cne_1.dlg
...
7000_12_lig_cne_1.dlg

7000_01_lig_cne_2.dlg
7000_02_lig_cne_2.dlg
7000_03_lig_cne_2.dlg
...
7000_12_lig_cne_2.dlg

7000_01_lig_cne_3.dlg
7000_02_lig_cne_3.dlg
7000_03_lig_cne_3.dlg
...
7000_12_lig_cne_3.dlg
```

I need to group these files based on the second column of their names (01, 02, 03 .. 12), thus creating 1000 folders, which should contain 12 files for each system in the following manner:

```
 Folder1, name: 7000_lig_cne_1, it contains 12 files:   7000_{this is from 01 to 12}_lig_cne_1.dlg

 Folder2, name: 7000_lig_cne_2, it contains 12 files 7000_{this is from 01 to 12}_lig_cne_2.dlg
...
 Folder1000, name: 7000_lig_cne_1000, it contains 12 files 7000_{this is from 01 to 12}_lig_cne_1000.dlg
```

Assuming that all *.dlg files are present within the same dir, I propose bash loop workflow, which only lack some sorting function (sed, awk ??), organized in the following manner:

```
#set the name of folder with all DLG
home=$PWD
FILES=${home}/all_DLG/7000_CNE
# set the name of protein and ligand library to analyse
experiment="7000_CNE"

#name of the output
output=${home}/sub_folders_to_analyse

#now here all magic comes
rm -r ${output}
mkdir ${output}

# sed solution
for i in ${FILES}/*.dlg        # define this better to suit your needs
do 
    n=$( <<<"$i" sed 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\)\.dlg$/\1/' )
    # move the file to proper dir
    mkdir -p ${output}/"${experiment}_lig$n"
    cp "$i" ${output}/"${experiment}_lig$n"
done
```

**Note**: there I indicated beginning of the name of each folder as `${experiment}` to which I add the number of the final column $n at the end. Would it be rather possible to set up each time the name of the new folder automatically based on the name of the copied files?

Manually it could be achieved via skipping the second column in the name of the folder

```
 cp ./all_DLG/7000_*_lig_cne_987.dlg ./output/7000_lig_cne_987
```

Comment: `Folder1000, name: 7000_lig_cne_3` ? Think you meant `Folder1000, name: 7000_lig_cne_1000` or `Folder3, name: 7000_lig_cne_3`? `some sorting expression` _Why_ do you need to _sort_ the files? You do not need order between files - just move the files to proper directory!.

Comment: yes you are right, I corrected my message. AND YES I NEED just to move filles sorry I could not find another proper expression.. mb rather redirecting according to file name ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over files. Extract the destination directory name from the filename. Move the file.

```
for i in *.dlg; do
    # extract last number with your favorite tool
    n=$( <<<"$i" sed 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\)\.dlg$/\1/' )
    # move the file to proper dir
    echo mkdir -p "folder$n"
    echo mv "$i" "folder$n"
done
```

Notes:

- Do not use upper case variables in your scripts. Use lower case variables.
- Remember to quote variables expansions.
- Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net
- Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/LeafyJoyousWireframe#main.sh)

**update:** for OP's foldernaming convention:

```
for i in *.dlg; do
    foldername="$HOME/output/${i%%_*}_${i#*_*_}"
    echo mkdir -p "$foldername"
    echo mv "$i" "$foldername"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
ls *.dlg | 
parallel --dry-run 'd={=s/^(7000_).*(lig.*)\.dlg/$1$2/=};mkdir -p $d;mv {} $d'
```

Pipe the output of `ls` command listing files ending in `.dlg` to parallel, which creates directories and moves the files to them.

Run the solution as is, and when satisfied the output of the dry run is ok, remove the option `--dry-run`.

The solution could be one instruction:

```
parallel 'd={=s/^(7000_).*(lig.*)\.dlg/$1$2/=};mkdir -p $d;mv {} $d' ::: *.dlg
```

Comment: it looks interesting but rather I would be interesting in some more automatic sollution capable to copy files to the directories and set up the name of the directory according to the file name, I've just edited my fist question!

Comment: @JamesStarlight if you want to copy instead of move swap `cp` for `mv`, the solution above uses the file to create a directory as requested (see `$d` variable).

Comment: Probably prefer `printf '%s\n'` over `ls`

Comment: @tripleee see 2nd solution

Answer (score 1):

Using POSIX shell's built-in grammar only and `sort`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

curdir=

# Create list of files with newline
# Safe since we know there is no special
# characters in name
printf -- %s\\n *.dlg |

# Sort the list by 5th key with _ as field delimiter
sort -t_ -k5 |

# Iterate reading the _ delimited fields of the sorted list
while IFS=_ read -r _ _ c d e; do

  # Compose the new directory name
  newdir="${c}_${d}_${e%.dlg}"

  # If we enter a new group / directory
  if [ "$curdir" != "$newdir" ]; then

    # Make the new directory current
    curdir="$newdir"

    # Create the new directory
    echo mkdir -p "$curdir"

    # Move all its files into it
    echo mv -- *_"$curdir.dlg" "$curdir/"
  fi
done
```

Optionally as a `sort` and `xargs` arguments stream:

```sh
printf -- %s\\n * |
sort -u -t_ -k5 
xargs -n1 sh -c 
'd="lig_cne_${0##*_}"
d="${d%.dlg}"
echo mkdir -p "$d"
echo mv -- *"_$d.dlg" "$d/"
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple `awk` script that do the trick in single sweep.

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN{FS="[_.]"} # make field separator "_" or "."
{ # for each filename
  dirName=$1"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5; # compute the target dir name from fields
  sysCmd = "mkdir -p " dirName"; cp "$0 " "dirName; # prepare bash command
  system(sysCmd); # run bash command
}
```

#### running `script.awk`

```
ls -1 *.dlg | awk -f script.awk
```

#### oneliner `awk` script

```
ls -1 *.dlg | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[_.]"}{d=$1"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5;system("mkdir -p "d"; cp "$0 " "d);}'
```

Comment: sorry I could not understand where your AWK script copy all of the folders. E.g. in my loop example I devined as $OUTPUT